# React dom elements get loaded but actually doesn't show up in the browser

Tags: reactjs, components, render

I have a search component which brings along the assets as per the search done.The problem is that render is getting called with the correct collection of assets and moreover it shows up in the dom element.I fail to understand why doesn't it show up in the actual browser window.

```
{this.state.data.map(function (asset) {
                // Asset Card
                {
                    return (<AssetCard asset={asset} defaultValues={this.props.defaultValues}
                                       allAssetDetails={this.state.data}
                                       triggerGetAssetDocId={this.getAssetDocId} key={asset.code}/>);
                }
            }, this)}
```

This is kind of the parent component which calls the child component which actually displays the asset cards based on the search. The child component looks like,

```
 <div className="card animated small fadeInDown">
            {/* Card Overlay - Selection */}
            <div className="select" onClick={this.selectAsset}>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="filled-in"
                        name={asset.thumbnails != null &&
                        asset.thumbnails[k]
                        }
                    />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="card-overlay modal-trigger" data-target="asset-detail" id={asset.docId}
                 dbId={asset.dbId} code={asset.code} key={asset.code}
                 onClick={(e) => this.props.triggerGetAssetDocId(e)}>
            </div>
            {/* Card Image */}
            <div className="card-image">

            </div>
            <div className="card-details">
                {/* Card Content */}
                <div className="card-content">
                    <span className="asset-name truncate">{asset.title}</span>
                    <div className="right">

                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* Card Action */}
                <div className="card-action">
                    <span className="views">
                        <span class="jdicon-eye-open jdicon"></span>
                        {asset.vcount}
                    </span>
                    <span className="downloads">
                        <span class="jdicon-download jdicon"></span>
                        {asset.dcount}
                    </span>
                    <div className="right">
                        {/* <a className="add-wishlist"/> */}
                        <span className="badge img-format" data-format={assetFormat}>
                        {assetFormat}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Can someone please point out where my approach could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your "asset" data that you are sending from your parent to child will be transferred via properties so can be assessed via "this.props"  ,
Suppose if you want to get the title you can do this.props.asset.title.
Similarly, you can also access the other data.
Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi @VipulSingh Thanks for your input.However I found out that my problem was due to interaction of unrelated components i.e. that weren't parent-child. Fixing the flow fixed my problem.